# Get an error when testing and making a fake photo

Tags: php, laravel

I'm a beginner in Laravel and still learning, when I wanted to do a fake file upload test I got an error

```
public function testUpload()
{
    $picture = UploadedFile::fake()->image('blabla.png');

    $this->post('/file/upload',[
        'picture' => $picture
    ])->assertSeeText("OK blabla.png");
}
```

> Error: Call to undefined function
> Illuminate\Http\Testing\imagecreatetruecolor()

in the learning video that I saw, a blabla.png file appeared in the folder storage

Answer (score 0):

Try using valid import

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/http-tests#testing-file-uploads

```
use Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile;
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume it's about the PHP GD library not related to Laravel or the code. The code seems OK to me

Install PHP GD Library and try

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php-gd
```